# I want only that Accordion load on click

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, lazy-loading, accordion

I googled the shit out of this :), I have a website; http://haagsepopmaand.nl/, 
There a lot of events on that page, in every event there are some pictures and some youtube movies. And it gets loaded all at once.

So I'm looking for a solution, I want the accordion to only load when clicked. I don't even know where to begin :(, I tried lazy loading the youtube videos but it doesn't work.

Maye you guys have any (quick and dirty) solutions?

Comment: Please explain what you've actually tried, and supply some source code. People aren't going to visit your website to see how things are structured.

Answer (score -1):

Here are some ugly and dirty ways I could think of....
1. You could separate out the accordion content elsewhere and make an ajax call to load the content when clicked.
2. You can have the content in the page stored in a javascript variable and load it when clicked.

Comment: Your answer deserves more to be posted as a comment than a conclusive answer.